# How can I set navigationOptions when using Apollo?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo

I'm working on a React Native app with React Navigation and Apollo.

To set the header title, you usually use `navigationOptions`:

```
class DemoComponent extends React.Component {

  public static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam("myParam", "Default title")
  })

  public render() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

With Apollo, I'm wrapping my component in another:

```
export default () => (
  <DemoMutation mutation={DEMO_MUTATION}>
    {(mutation, result) => <DemoComponent mutation={mutation} result={result} />}
  </JoinGroupMutation>
);
```

This means that `navigationOptions` never gets read, and the header title is empty. I've tried passing down `navigation` as a prop but that doesn't work (`navigationOptions` is a static function and doesn't rely on props).

I can think of a workaround, e.g. using a custom header component and then passing down the `navigation` prop from the `<DemoMutation>` component and then manually calling `navigation.setParam()`. This seems a bit counterintuitive, though -- is there a more straightforward way of using `navigationOptions` in a nested component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is hoisting the static function to the higher-order component. There's a library called [`hoist-non-react-statics`](https://github.com/mridgway/hoist-non-react-statics) that does exactly this.

```
export default hoistNonReactStatics(DemoMutation, DemoComponent);
```